# Menu items in BottomNavigationView not centered

Tags: java, xml, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation view that has no icons, only text fields.

I want to center the text vertically & horizontally and added a highlight for the different states:

```
topnavigationview.setItemBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mainactivitybackgroundhighlight_top);
```

with the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/blau" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/blau" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/dunkelgraublau" />
</selector>
```

The view is included like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/top_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/include4"
            android:background="@color/dunkelgraublau"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/weiß"
            app:menu="@menu/top_navigation_menu" />
```

however, it now looks like this:

[image]

as you can see the highlight does not cover half of the menu, more like 40% of it; when selecting the right hand item its the same - despite the width being set to match_parent.

the text also is neither centered vertically nor horizontally;

1) how do i center the menu text vertically within the layout?

2) how do i make it so both menu items take up 50% of the navigation view? this would center the text horizontally and make the highlight take up 50% as intended.

Answer (score 6):

The real answer is: don't do this. You're trying to use a support design library component that was created to look and feel a certain way, but you want to make it look and feel a different way. You should create your own view to behave the way you want.

But...

> 1) how do i center the menu text vertically within the layout?

Digging into the implementation for `BottomNavigationView`, we eventually find that the menu items are represented by `BottomNavigationItemView` objects (derived from `FrameLayout`), which use this layout: https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-design/blob/master/res/layout/design_bottom_navigation_item.xml

As such, we can create a method to adjust the gravity and padding on the label views' parent so that they appear centered:

```
private static void adjustGravity(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == android.support.design.R.id.smallLabel) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
        parent.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        parent.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;

        for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
            adjustGravity(vg.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

> 2) how do i make it so both menu items take up 50% of the navigation view?

The width of each menu item is constrained by this code in the `BottomNavigationMenuView` class:

> ```
> mActiveItemMaxWidth = res.getDimensionPixelSize(
>         R.dimen.design_bottom_navigation_active_item_max_width);
> ```

There's no good way to modify this value, but we can do so using reflection:

```
private static void adjustWidth(BottomNavigationView nav) {
    try {
        Field menuViewField = nav.getClass().getDeclaredField("mMenuView");
        menuViewField.setAccessible(true);
        Object menuView = menuViewField.get(nav);

        Field itemWidth = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mActiveItemMaxWidth");
        itemWidth.setAccessible(true);
        itemWidth.setInt(menuView, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // TODO
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Once you have these methods in your activity, you can just write this:

```
BottomNavigationView nav = findViewById(R.id.top_navigation_view);
adjustGravity(nav);
adjustWidth(nav);
```

Note that, because each of these methods relies on internal implementation details of `BottomNavigationView`, they are always subject to breakage when you update the support/design libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth reply, works like a charm! I am aware that these kind of support lib modifications are not best practice and will work on a more elegant solution later down the road. Your 2nd method contains two // TODO comments; what would you code there, exactly?

Comment: @TeraGerard up to you. If those exceptions are thrown, the view widths won't be changed. If you don't care, then you can do nothing (or send a non-fatal error message to your logging system so that you can see that something has broken). If you **do** care, then you'll have to add code that can try a different solution, or perhaps simply `throw new RuntimeException(e)` to crash your app.

Answer (score 2):

This answer helps me. This is the Ben P.'s kotlin version:

```
    private fun adjustGravity(v: View) {
        if (v.id == android.support.design.R.id.smallLabel) {
            val parent = v.parent as ViewGroup
            parent.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)

            val params = parent.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            parent.layoutParams = params
        }

        if (v is ViewGroup) {
            val vg = v as ViewGroup

            for (i in 0 until vg.childCount) {
                adjustGravity(vg.getChildAt(i))
            }
        }
    }

    private fun adjustWidth(nav: BottomNavigationView) {
        try {
            val menuViewField = nav.javaClass.getDeclaredField("mMenuView")
            menuViewField.isAccessible = true
            val menuView = menuViewField.get(nav)

            val itemWidth = menuView.javaClass.getDeclaredField("mActiveItemMaxWidth")
            itemWidth.isAccessible = true
            itemWidth.setInt(menuView, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
            // TODO
        } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
            // TODO
        }
    }
```

Then...

```
    val bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)

    adjustGravity(bottomNavigationView)
    adjustWidth(bottomNavigationView)
```

[image]

Comment: On AndroidX support library you need to change **android.support.design.R.id.smallLabel** to **com.google.android.material.R.id.smallLabel**